# iPhone camera toolbar buttons

Tags: iphone, xcode

The iPhone camera toolbar holds the following buttons: cancel/record

I would like to change the cancel button to the small image button that takes me to the photo library.

I wasn't sure if i need to use the overlay or does the xcode have something more comfortable in this case since this is something well known and used.

Is there something like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set overlayView to your `UIImagePickerController`

```
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = yourOverlayView;
```

Answer (score 0):

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

> You can customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in “Capturing Still Images or Movies.” You can display your custom overlay view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls. Custom overlay views for the UIImagePickerController class are available in iOS 3.1 and later by way of the cameraOverlayView property. For a code example, see the PhotoPicker sample code project.